# SAS transpose wide format to long format

Tags: sas

I have a SAS dataset that I need to transpose from wide format to long format
data that I have:

```
DATES  Year1   Year2   Year3
Jan      100    200     300
```

Data I want:

```
DATES  Year  Income
Jan     1      100
Jan     2       200
Jan     3       300
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario the syntax for `proc transpose` is fairly simple.

```
proc transpose data=have out=want(rename=(_name_=Year col1=Income));
by date;
var year:; * the ':' is a wildcard character;
run;
```

The resulting output:

```
Obs    date    Year    Income

 1     Jan     year1      100
 2     Jan     year2      200
 3     Jan     year3      300
```